# Reading data in a list from xml in python

Tags: python

```
   -<randomints count = 5>
       <ints>-2,-2,-2,-2,-2</ints>
       <ints>-2,-2,-1,-2,-2</ints>
       <ints>-2,-2,-2,-1,-2</ints>
    </randomints>
```

I used `xml.etree.ElementTree`

```
Ints = []
for child in root.findall('randomints'):
    Ints = [l.text for l in child]
```

I am getting output as `['-2,-2,-2,-2,-2','-2,-2,-1,-2,-2','-2,-2,-2,-1,-2']`

But I need the output as `[[-2,-2,-2,-2,-2],[-2,-2,-1,-2,-2],[-2,-2,-2,-1,-2]]`

Comment: You could try this: `Ints = [[int(el) for el in l.text.split(',')] for l in child]`. Ultimately you just need to do some processing on the `l.text` that you are getting. Keep in mind that calling `int` on non numeric/integer-like objects will raise `ValueError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("infile.xml")

for child in root.findall('randomints'):
    ints = [list(map(int, l.text.split(","))) for l in child]

print(ints)
```

Output:

```
[[-2, -2, -2, -2, -2], [-2, -2, -1, -2, -2], [-2, -2, -2, -1, -2]]
```

Comment: As an aside, I found that `ElementTree.parse` would **not** load your xml as `<randomints count = 5>`, and instead it had to be `<randomints count = "5">`...